# start command in linux

Tags: shell-script, centos, jobs

I have a custom script which runs on a cPanel server (CentOS 6) which is as below. It starts a service on the specified port which accepts incoming data.
It uses **start** command and runs ok.

```
#!/bin/bash
PORT_NUMBER=xxxx
echo "Start Time: $(date)"
if sudo netstat -altpn|grep xxxx | grep -q 'CLOSE_WAIT'; then
echo "Found Close Wait"
sudo stop comm
sleep 60
sudo stop comm
sudo lsof -i tcp:${PORT_NUMBER} | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:xxxx)
sleep 60
sudo start comm
fi
if [[ $(sudo lsof -t -i:2010) ]]; then
    echo "Service Running"
else
    echo "Restarting Service"
    sudo start comm
fi
```

Which start command produces `/sbin/start`

I have copied this script to a newer server with CentOS 7. When i try to run it, it gives the following error.

```
Start Time: Mon Sep 20 12:09:36 UTC 2021
Restarting Service
sudo: start: command not found
End Time: Mon Sep 20 12:09:36 UTC 2021
```

I tried searching for a package to install, which provides the start command. I was unable to find such package. Any ideas which package I need to install on CentOS 7 server.

**Update**
The comm job was defined in the /etc/init/comm.conf and was being called as the parameter for the start command.

```
description "Daemon Service running on port xxxx to receive device files"
author "xxxxxxxxxx"

start on startup
stop on shutdown
respawn

script
    [ $(exec /usr/bin/php -f /home/xxxxxxx/scripts/comm.php &>> /home/xxxxxxx/scripts/log.txt) = 'ERROR' ] && ( stop; exit 1; )
end script
```

Comment: `/sbin/start` is probably part of the `upstart` system initialization daemon. `upstart` was replaced by `systemd` on newer Linux distributions. (I don't know when/if this happened in CentOS.) In this case, you have to adapt the script and maybe other parts of a related software/service to `systemd`. What is the script supposed to? Where does this script come from? Please [edit] your question to add more information, don't use comments to answer.

Comment: Your small change to your question does not make it much clearer. Does "*custom script*" mean that you wrote it and you know how it's supposed to work? Or did you get it from someone you cannot ask for help? What is the service `comm`? Did you implement it? How do you install it on CentOS 6 and 7? Show all code that is related to the installation of the service. (Obviously your script does more than "*start[s] a service on the specified port which accepts incoming data*", as this would be a simple `sudo start comm`.)

Comment: Hi, yes, it was a script written by some one else. I am attempting to migrate it to another server. I will check the details of the comm job and post here if i find them

Comment: **Please [edit] your question and add all information there.**

Comment: You’d probably be better off throwing away both files and creating a systemd unit to start the PHP process.  You don’t need the extra logging because the journal captures it all.